How to export and import keymaps?
I got a new PC and want to import the keymaps. ChatGPT told me to do this:
dconf dump /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ > keyboard_shortcuts_backup.txt

dconf load /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/ < keyboard_shortcuts_backup.txt

I did it and restarted the pc but somehow nothing changed.
How can I trouble shoot it?

The command above just exports settings in scheme-path /org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/. But other keymaps are stored for example in scheme-path org/gnome/mutter/keybindings. That's why some were missing.
With that command dconf dump / > settings_backup.txt I exported everything. That file includes lots of settings which may not be suitable for a new device. Therefore I will remove the lines I don't need and then import it again.
dconf load / < settings_backup.txt
